# is it possible to calculate the total of a column in group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql query which produces the following table, But I want to be able to obtain the total for the marked columns which are grouped by category:
[image]

here is the code:

```
select pic.Name as Category,
pis.Code as Code,
pis.Name as Issue,
count(it.ID) as  'total count',
sum(mc.ots) as 'Imps',
sum(case when ito.rating <50 then 1 else 0 end) as 'unfav count',
sum(case when ito.Rating =50  then 1 else 0 end) as 'neu count',
sum(case when ito.Rating >50  then 1 else 0 end) as 'fav count',

(sum(case when ito.rating < 50 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / count(it.ID) * 100) as 'unfav %',
(sum(case when ito.Rating =50  then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / count(it.ID) * 100) as 'neu %',
(sum(case when ito.Rating >50  then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / count(it.ID) * 100) as 'fav %',

CONVERT(decimal(4,2),avg(ito.Rating)) as 'Av Rating %',

count(it.id) * 100.0 / sum(count(it.ID)) OVER () AS [% of Count],
sum(mc.ots) * 100.0 / sum(sum(mc.ots)) OVER () AS [% Imps]

from 
Profiles P 
INNER JOIN ProfileResults PR ON P.ID = PR.ProfileID
INNER JOIN Items it ON PR.ItemID = It.ID
inner join Batches b on b.ID=it.BatchID
left outer join BatchActionHistory bah on b.ID=bah.batchid
inner join itemorganisations oit (nolock) on it.id=oit.itemid
inner join itemorganisations ito (nolock) on it.id=ito.itemid
inner join itemorganisationIssues ioi (nolock) on ito.id=ioi.itemorganisationid
inner join ProjectIssues pis (nolock)on ioi.IssueID = pis.ID
inner join ProjectIssueCategories pic (nolock)on pic.ID = pis.CategoryID
inner join Lookup_ItemStatus lis (nolock) on lis.ID = it.StatusID
inner join Lookup_BatchStatus lbs (nolock) on lbs.ID = b.StatusID
inner join Lookup_BatchTypes bt on bt.id = b.Typeid
inner join Lookup_MediaChannels mc on mc.id = it.MediaChannelID


where p.ID = @profileID 
and b.StatusID IN (6,7)
and bah.BatchActionID = 6
and it.StatusID = 2
and it.IsRelevant = 1


Group BY pic.Name,pis.Name,pis.Code
order by pic.name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the `sum()` windows function.  You can actually nest it with regular aggregation functions.  So:

```
sum(count(it.ID)) over () as TotalCnt,
sum(sum(mc.ots)) over () as TotalImps
```

This assumes that you are using SQL Server 2005 or greater.

That does it for the "whole column".  For a subgroup, such as those defined by a category, the same idea holds (as pointed out by Alexander):

sum(count(it.ID)) over (partition by category) as CategoryCnt,
    sum(sum(mc.ots)) over (partition by category) as CategoryImps

Comment: does this sum only the totals for that group or the whole resultset?

Comment: @xerxes in answer suggested by Gordon Linnhoff try add OVER(PARTITION BY pis.Code)

Answer (score 2):

Read about `WITH ROLLUP` clause (or grouping sets, available in later releases of sql server - I dont' know which one are you using).
It will group your output by combinations of columns from `GROUP BY` (3 columns group by, 2 columns group by, 1 column group by and grand total). You can then distinguish grouped columns with GROUPING(column_name)=1 when it's aggregated. 
Hope this helps.